# How to group data by two fields?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to group data in pyspark DataFrame, and I do it as follows, when I have only one field `field1`:

```
groups = df.select("field1").distinct().flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
dfs = [df.where(df["field1"] == g) for g in groups]
```

I get the list `dfs` of N DataFrame's, where N is the size of `groups`. Now I want to use `field1` and `field2` for grouping my data.

How can I do it?

Also, I would like to know if using List of DataFrame is a good approach? I then use `dfs` in the for loop: `for d in dfs`. But this for loop is really slow.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do exactly but does groupBy("field1","field2") works ?

Comment: Is there a chance that you could post your dataframe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only interested in grouping by two specific columns then use [`groupBy`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.groupBy). A simple example using two columnss:

```
val df2 = df.groupBy('col1', 'col2')
```

After performing `groupBy`, usually you have to use an aggregation function with `agg`, see [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData) for available options.

---

If what you need is a list of all combinations of two columns, then an alternative would be to loop over them and perform the `groupBy`. However, `groupBy` is notorious for being a slow and inefficient. Depending on what you need to aggregate, it could be a good idea to look into `reduceByKey` or `combineByKey`.